# Прошу подсказать как сделать обработку ошибок в aiogram

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiogram

Я пишу телеграм бота на python aiogram. Подскажите пожалуйста как можно сделать обработчик ошибок? К примеру пользователь спамит командой, у него появлется сообщение от бота `"Вы не можете использовать данную команду, вам нужно подождать столько то секунд"`.
Или если `бот не может написать пользователю, так как пользователь не писал боту` или `бот заблокирован у пользователя.` Ну и другие распространённые ошибки. Как их можно улавливать?
Желательно одним handler'ом.

Comment: AntiFlood -> https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/examples/middleware_and_antiflood.html

Comment: Комментарий выше - отличный пример. Его можно под себя переделать  и вешать эти декораторы на хендлеры

Comment: благодарю за помощь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это перед командой

```
@dp.throttled(antiflood, rate=3)
async def antiflood(*args):
    m = args[0]
    await m.answer(msg.antiflood)
```